# Lazy loading, change detection and observable issue in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, observable

I've been struggling for a while with the following issue in an Angular 2.3 application (using Webpack): I try to lazily display my data (personal bookmarks) via an **Observable** object when I go to **personal** (user bookmarks) route, but it only gets rendered in the browser **the second time** when I click on the **Personal** link, although behind the scenes the data is loaded initially (GET request goes through successfully). Seems to be some sort of change detection issue with my configuration... I will list below the components that are involved:

The navigation code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']" routerLinkActive="active">
    <img src="/img/logo.png" width="35" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Bookmarks
  </a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['personal']" routerLinkActive="active">Personal</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['personal/new']" routerLinkActive="active">New personal bookmark</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**app.routing.ts** snippet:

```
  {
    path: 'personal',
    loadChildren: './personal/user-bookmarks.module#UserBookmarksModule'
  }
```

Personal bookmars module (lazy loaded):

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: UserBookmarksComponent },
    {
      path: 'new',
      component: UserBookmarkFormComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'bookmarks/:id',
      component: BookmarkDetailComponent
    },
  ])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserBookmarksRoutingModule {}
```

The UserBookmarksComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-user-bookmarks',
  templateUrl: './user-bookmarks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-bookmarks.component.scss']
})
export class UserBookmarksComponent implements  OnInit{

  userBookmarks: Observable<List<Bookmark>>;

  constructor(private userBookmarkStore: UserBookmarkStore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userBookmarks = this.userBookmarkStore.getBookmarks();
  }

}
```

The **user-bookmarks.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <hr>
  <h3>Personal bookmarks</h3>
  <my-async-user-bookmark-list [bookmarks]="userBookmarks"></my-async-user-bookmark-list>
</div>
```

The **AsyncUserBookmarksListComponent** that gets the **userBookmarks** as input

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-async-user-bookmark-list',
  templateUrl: './async-user-bookmark-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./async-user-bookmark-list.component.scss']
})
export class AsyncUserBookmarksListComponent{

  @Input()
  bookmarks: Observable<Bookmark[]>;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private userBookmarkStore: UserBookmarkStore) {}

  /**
   *
   * @param bookmark
   */
  gotoDetail(bookmark: Bookmark): void {
    console.log("At least lands in the method........");
    let link = ['./bookmarks', bookmark._id];
    this.router.navigate(link, { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  deleteBookmark(bookmark:Bookmark): void {

    let obs = this.userBookmarkStore.deleteBookmark(bookmark);
    obs.subscribe(
      res => {
        this.router.navigate(['/personal']);
      });
  }

}
```

And finally the **async-user-bookmark-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let bookmark of bookmarks | async" class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title"><a href="{{bookmark.location}}" target="_blank">{{ bookmark.name }}</a></h4>
    <p class="card-text">{{ bookmark.description }}</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoDetail(bookmark)">Edit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteBookmark(bookmark)">Delete</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <b>Tags:</b>
    <ul class="tags">
      <li *ngFor="let tag of bookmark.tags">{{tag}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <b>Category:</b> {{ bookmark.category }}
  </div>
</div>
```

> Also when I click delete a bookmark from the personal list, it gets deleted behind the scenes, but the change is propagated to the personal bookmarks list, until I click again on the **personal** link...

The complete project is available at https://github.com/Codingpedia/bookmarks/tree/feature/move_delete_to_personal_bookmarks

Your input is very much appreciated. thanks

Comment: GitHub search isn't able to find `UserBookmarkStore` in your project :-/

Comment: I ran `npm start` from your project and got this: `VM315:1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Can't add property fileName, object is not extensible
    at Object.Linter`

Comment: Sorry @GünterZöchbauer, 
The link pointed to the master branch, I corrected that now...

Comment: Search still doesn't work. Perhaps GitHub has yet to index the added code. The project seems to be too complex anyway to investigate like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: need the code for the UserBookmarkStore, need to know where that's provided as well.